# How do I return information from a single form from a django modelformset, getting validation error

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to use django modelformset to display and collect information on the webpage.  I want to use the submitted form information elsewhere in the application.  However, when I submit the form it won't validate. I am getting the this error message: `ValidationError: ['ManagementForm data is missing o$  has been tampered with']`

I think what is happening is that I am using the modelformset incorrectly and I am submitting a single form instead of the formset.  To build my page I loop over each form within the formset and create subforms with their own submit buttons.  Is this a misuse of a modelformset?

The behavior I would like to have is the user enters new values for `new_field` and clicks submit on the form. Then `field1` and `new_field`for only that row are submitted back to views.py.  Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated

views.py

```
def query_page(request):
    PipelineFormset = modelformset_factory(Pipeline, form=PipelineForm)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PipelineFormset(request.POST)
        print('form recieved')
        if form.is_valid():
            print('valid')
            # further processing and redirect
    formset = PipelineFormset()
    return render(request, 'lio/query.html', {
        'formset': formset})
```

forms.py

```
class PipelineForm(ModelForm):
    new_field = forms.CharField(max_length=2)

    class Meta:
        model = Pipeline
        fields = '__all__'
```

template.html

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Field1</th>
      <th scope="col">New_field</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
    <form action={%  url 'query' %} method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <tr>
      <td scope="row">
        {{ form.field1.value }}
        {{ form.field1.as_hidden}}
      </td>
      <td scope="row">
        {{ form.new_field}}
      </td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Run"></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </form>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

models.py

```
class Pipeline(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=4)
```

I see this post with a nearly identical title, but I am not using prefixes, so I think it is unrelated [Django ModelFormset Validation Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46075267/django-modelformset-validation-error)

Comment: A `FormSet` always uses prefixes (although the logic is hidden). The reason why the prefixes are used is to make a distinction between the individual forms.

Comment: Why do you wrap the forms in the `formset` in individual `<form>`s? Normally you span a `<form>` over all the subforms.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I am pretty new to Django/HTML.  I updated my code and the template above.  However, i am  still getting the ['ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with'] error.  Is my formset.management form in the wrong location?